# Set ascii const in utf8 class

Tags: php

I need to specify some const (terminators).

File is UTF8 encoded.

```
class Base {
  const PROTO = chr(2) . chr(2) . chr(3) . chr(1);
  function test($str) {
    if (substr(str,0,4) == self::PROTO) {
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

as for now using late initializing:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->_proto = chr(2) . chr(2) . chr(3) . chr(1);
}
```

So just interesting if there possibility to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify them as a string of characters in octal notation like `const PROTO = "\2\2\3\1"` or if you prefer hexadecimal `const PROTO = "\x2\x2\x3\x1"`.

What [`chr(n)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) does is return the ASCII character specified by the number `n` which is in decimal notation. You can get the same thing in a [double-quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) if you convert `n` to either octal or hexadecimal first, then prefix it with `\` or `\x` respectively.

All the numbers happen to remain the same in the example here because they're all under 8, and so have the same digits in all three notations. If instead you wanted a vertical tab character you could specify it either as `chr(11)` (decimal), `"\xB"` (hexadecimal), or `"\13"` (octal).

There's a handy ASCII table at http://www.asciitable.com/ which gives you all three notations for each character.